# Poblema con el Keyboard y Edittext

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Tengo un `edittext` dentro de un `listview` con adaptador personalizado, en ese `edittext` yo ingreso cantidades y tengo un `textview` donde se muestra la suma de lo ingresado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando ingreso un cantidad de mil o mayor al quintar el keyboard como que me borra esa cantidad, pero si la hago de menor cantidad de 1000 sí me lo deja.

Les dejo codigo de mi validacion donde hago la suma

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {

        //Abono = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono);
       DetalleCxP O_DetalleCxP = (DetalleCxP)((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).getTag();
        O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado=ONC_SYS.NullToZeroDouble(s.toString());

        Double Total=0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<DetalleArrayList.size();i++)
        {
            if (((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado>0)
            {
                Total += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado;
            }
        }
        DecimalFormat numberFormat  = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Total)).setText(numberFormat.format(Total));

        if (Total==0)
        {
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pagoceros)).setEnabled(true);
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pagoceros)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(true);
        }

        //Validacion que no te deje hacer un abono Mayo al saldo vencido
        if (O_DetalleCxP.getSaldo() < O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No puedes Aplicar un Abono Mayor al SaldoVencido",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: alguien que me ayude?

Comment: Por favor usa las etiquetas adecuadas. Acabo de colocarle la etiqueta `android`.